# Give same width to items vertically positioned

Tags: tailwind-css

I have two items positioned vertically, and I'd like the narrower one is as wide as the wider one.

My code looks like

```html
<div class="flex flex-col items-end">
  <div>This should take all the space</div>
  <div class="flex flex-row gap-x-4">
    <div> this is the first element</div>
    <div> this is the second element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and produce

[image]

However, I would like the result to be

[image]

`items-end` is needed because the items are displayed on the right side of the page.

I have tried to mess with positioning, but I cannot achieve the final result I'm looking for.

Can anyone give me a hand on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shrink-wrap the container and then right align it:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex flex-col w-max ml-auto">
  <div>This should take all the space</div>
  <div class="flex flex-row gap-x-4">
    <div> this is the first element</div>
    <div> this is the second element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also use a grid layout with one grid column track sized to `max-content` and then align the grid column track to the right:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-[max-content] justify-end">
  <div>This should take all the space</div>
  <div class="flex flex-row gap-x-4">
    <div> this is the first element</div>
    <div> this is the second element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the grid layout works just fine.